# Calculating Expected Value of a Streak

Tags: r, distributions

What is the expected length of a streak of heads or tails when flipping a coin? What distribution is this?

I'm pretty sure the answer is 2. But I don't know what distributions it is..

I did the following R code:

```
l=10000
longest.stk = avg.stk = numeric(l)
for(i in 1:l){
x=sample(0:1, 1000, repl=T)
r = rle(x) 
longest.stk[i] = max(r$lengths)  
avg.stk[i] = mean(r$lengths) }
mean(longest.stk) 
[1] 10.3001
mean(avg.stk)           
[1] 2.000825
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the expected value of a [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with $p=0.5$, which is $1/(1-p)$.